# Help : rejected versus decline

Tags: word-choice

Can somene help ? I am still struggeling on "rejected,refuses and decline"

How should the following espressed in common English ?

Our proposal / offer was rejected or declined / refused by or from the customer/company ?

Comment: proposals are said to be rejected. People decline invitations. And I refuse to give you an answer. :)

Comment: @Lambie I reject your refusal to answer, but decline to comment why.  :)

Comment: @Andrew Well, no worries then. I accept your rejection. :)

Comment: @ Lambie & Andrew - Really funny :-)

Answer (score 3):

*Decline X* means you do not want X, but doesn't necessarily imply that there is anything wrong with X.

*Reject X* is related to two Latin words together meaning "throw back".  It means not only do you not want X, but you think X is bad and needs to return to where it came from.  It implies you think there is something wrong with X.

*Refuse X* comes from French words that are related to "reject".  It has similar meaning to *reject*, but doesn't have as strong of an implication that it should go back to where it came from to be fixed, it more implies you won't accept it.

*Reject* as a noun means "something/someone that was rejected," while *refuse* as a noun is pronounced differently and is synonymous with "garbage."  (Decline as a noun means a slant downward.)